# How can I prevent scrolling my UITableView when inserting a new row?

Tags: swift, uitableview

The goal of my app visually is to have the messages fill up from the bottom of the screen first, so on my UITableView and my UITableViewCell's I have `self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)`.

This seems to be making it extremely difficult to preserve the scroll position when inserting a new cell, which I'm doing by inserting at index 0 to the messages array, and then adding a row to indexpath row 0.

If you are scrolled to the bottom, it should scroll along with the new messages, but if you're scrolled back reading previous messages it shouldn't move at all when a new message comes in.

This code seems to be the best I could do so far, and it mostly works but there's a slight jitter sometimes when a message comes in and I'd like to fix that.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.beginUpdates()
    self.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    self.endUpdates()
    
    if (self.contentOffset.y > 0) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let height = self.rectForRow(at: indexPath).size.height
            print("New cell height: \(height)")
            
            var newScrollPosition = self.contentOffset
            newScrollPosition.y += height
            self.setContentOffset(newScrollPosition, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```